# Project ids of records which matched the predicate

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a following classes:

```cs
class A : IAggregateRoot
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public IEnumerable<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set;}
}

class B : ValueObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //no navigation upstream to A due to DDD restrictions
}
```

```cs
var bIds = new int[]{1,5,6,8,9};
```

What I want to do is to filter those `B`s(or their ids) that are associated with `A`s that are active (`IsActive` flag is `true`) . I don't know even where to start with this one.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Like `listofAs.Where(a= > a.IsActive).SelectMany(a => a.Bs)` perhaps?

Comment: Probably you are looking for this query: `context.A.Include(a => a.Bs.Where(b => b.IsActive && bIds.Contains(b.Id))).ToList();`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv This will give me `A`s but I still won't know which `B`s are actually the ones, maybe if I `SelectMany` `B`s and then do a intersection with `bIds`. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: From question is not clear what you really need. `context.A.SelectMany(a => a.Bs.Where(b => b.IsActive && bIds.Contains(b.Id))).ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var allBsInActiveAs = allAs.Where(a => a.IsActive)
    .SelectMany(a => a.Bs).Select(b => b.Id).Distinct().ToList();
```

1. the `Where()` filters all Active As.
2. the `SelectMany()` puts the Bs of those As to one List together.
3. the `Select()` only takes the Ids of those Bs
4. The `Distinct()` removes duplicate Id entries